# Create a directory for every element of a path if it does not exist

Tags: c++, c++14, std, c++17

In C++, I want to create a directory from a path `"path/that/consists/of/several/elements"`. Also I want to create all parent directories of that directory in case they are not existing. How to do that with std C++?

Comment: Then do that. Do you have a *specific* question?

Answer (score 12):

[`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)/[`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (C++14/C++17) provides [`create_directories()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory). It creates a directory for every path element if it does not already exist. For that it executes [`create_directory()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) for every such element.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // In C++17 use std::filesystem.

    try {
        fs::create_directories("path/with/directories/that/might/not/exist");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) { // Not using fs::filesystem_error since std::bad_alloc can throw too.
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If exception handling does not fit, [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) functions have overloads using [`std::error_code`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code):

```
int main() {
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // In C++17 use std::filesystem.

    std::error_code ec;
    bool success = fs::create_directories("path/with/directories/that/might/not/exist", ec);

    if (!success) {
        std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl; // Fun fact: In case of success ec.message() returns "The operation completed successfully." using vc++.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool create_directories( const std::filesystem::path& p, std::error_code& ec )` is not marked `noexcept` so it may also throw `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

With Boost:

```
boost::filesystem::path dir(to create);
if(boost::filesystem::create_directories(dir)) {
    std::cout << "Success" << "\n";
}
```

Or with platform dependent `system`:

```
system("mkdir " + to_create);
```