# std::filesystem::create_directories Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 15.8.2. I am trying to use the solution from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940515/create-a-directory-for-every-element-of-a-path-if-it-does-not-exist/43940516) to create a directory for every element of the path if it doesn't exist.

However, on line which calls `create_directories` I get an error: `namespace "std::experimental::filesystem" has no member "create_directories."`

I tried with both `std::experimental::filesystem` and `std::filesystem` with no success.

I tried changing c++ version in project properties to c++17 by setting the language standard to `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`, still same error.

When I step into filesystem namespace to see the header I see that there is no create_directories function.

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) there should be such a function, but in the header file I'm reading I only see the `path` class out of all those classes and functions. The location of the header file is: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include`

Here is how my code looks like:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>

int main(){
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // In C++17 use std::filesystem.

try {
    fs::create_directories("C:\\Program Files\\Test");
}
catch (std::exception& e) { // Not using fs::filesystem_error since std::bad_alloc can throw too.
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}
```

Comment: @Tas I just edited the question by adding the MCVE. Is it fine now?

Comment: You forgot to include `<filesystem>` header and it's no longer an experimental feature with `-std:c++17`: https://godbolt.org/z/TLZ9JR

Comment: I know, I already answered my own question. I edited my question just to be more clear, so it may help somebody else. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. The problem was that I forgot to include the experimental/filesystem header. Now everything's working perfectly. It was a silly mistake, but I am new to c++.

So, the solution was to add: `#include <experimental/filesystem>` to my code.

Here is how my code looks like now:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main(){
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // In C++17 use std::filesystem.

try {
    fs::create_directories("C:\\Program Files\\Test");
}
catch (std::exception& e) { // Not using fs::filesystem_error since std::bad_alloc can throw too.
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}
```

When I thought I was looking at the filesystem header file, I was acually looking at the fstream header file instead. That's why I couldn't find the functions I was looking for. The thing that tricked me was that fstream header also has a namespace called `filesystem`, so I was actually looking at that (since Visual Studio pointed me to that header, since it was the only header I included that has filesystem namespace in it.

Also, since I changed the language settings to ISO C++17 Standard I could also use `#include <filesystem>` and `std::filesystem` instead.

Comment: Did You set the language to C++17 in project properties? Then just include <filesystem>

Comment: Yes, that's working fine too (without experimental if I change the language setting to C++17). The problem was that I forgot to include filesystem at all. And the header file I was looking at was actually fstream (since I included it cause I was using it earlier) and fstream has a namespace that is also called filesystem, hence my confusion.